# Xcode crashing when adding Navigation Bar to storyboard.

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, crash, storyboard

I'm pretty new to Xcode, I have been experiencing crashes when adding a Navigation Bar to my storyboard.

When the Navi Bar is dragged over to the top of the storyboard, then I find that 'Title' has dropped to the bottom and then Xcode crashes.

Has anyone got any advice when trying to add the navigation bar?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to drag the navigation bar into a view controller that is embedded in a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: Yes, how can I correct this?

Comment: Why isn't the navigation bar showing by default? Did you set the "Top Bar" simulated metric to "None?"

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected the issue. Was the initial config, didn't have portrait as the only option selected.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure 'Device Orientation' is set to 'Portrait' only and not 'Landscape Left/Right' as it is when you start up a new project.